# Google Analytics Custom Report - How to restric to a specfic URL?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to create a custom report that will show traffic to a specific URL of your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this should answer your question, if that URL is a subdirectory over at [Google's Support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en).

> Filters allow you to limit and modify the traffic data that is included in a view. For example, you can use filters to exclude traffic from particular IP addresses, focus on a specific subdomain or directory, or convert dynamic page URLs into readable text strings.
>
> ### Predefined filters
>
> **Exclude/Include only traffic to the subdirectories**: use this filter to exclude/include only traffic to a particular subdirectory (such as www.example.com/motorcycles).

Also in the Support Article, they have a video to show you how to [setup the variable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08msFgeHw9M) that you needed also.